# Micorsoft parner Center API - is it possible to list all admin user of a customer ? or filter customer user based on userprincipal name?

Tags: azure, rest

Using following MS Partnmer center API, we can list all users 
https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers/{id}/users

is there any way so I can filter data based on userPrincipalname or I can list all admin users only ?
If yes can you provide me the request Query for it in REST

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can perform filter operation on the result of partner center API.

```
GET https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers/4d3cf487-70f4-4e1e-9ff1-b2bfce8d9f04/users HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Accept: application/json
MS-RequestId: 5d845377-5b7d-4cd4-98f6-19e5ae3faa81
MS-CorrelationId: 5a3d64d4-4490-4932-bf5e-0dc9a58f27ca
X-Locale: en-US
Host: api.partnercenter.microsoft.com
```

Filter will be something like below:

```
?filter{"Field":"userPrincipalName","Value":"cont","Operator":"starts_with"}

GET {baseURL}/v1/customers/4d3cf487-70f4-4e1e-9ff1-b2bfce8d9f04/users?size={size}&filter={filter} HTTP/1.1
```

You can refer below link for understanding more about filtering.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/get-a-customer-by-name#-rest-request

Hope it helps.